# How do I set up push notifications?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using react-native with firebase push notification. (android)

Notifications are set to come in the background. Notifications come well like this a picture below

[image]

But I also want to get notifications like this: How can this be set?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This requires a service working to listen to incoming messages from the FCM server, for FCM to know which device to send messages to, you must maintain the device token in a database that is associated with the user.

`React Native firebase` can change between versions but has a full breakdown of this process highlighted here: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

> React Native Firebase provides native integration of Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for both Android & iOS. FCM is a cost-free service, allowing for server-device and device-device communication. The React Native Firebase Messaging module provides a simple JavaScript API to interact with FCM.

This makes FCM very easy with `RNFirebase` - once you have your message handler setup, you can test them with Firebase Console's Notification Composer, an online FCM creator toolkit: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification